# Laravel Eloquent statement contains too many placeholders

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a lot of records for each table, and the relationship: `Purchase Order`(600 records) has many `From` (60,000 records) has many `manpower` (250,000 records). How can I optimize the Query in this case? And now show: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1390 Prepared statement contains too many placeholders`

I also need to calculate all manpower working hours. There are in and out timestamps. I need to calculate the total hours and sum them into total hours.

```
$purchaseOrder = PurchaseOrder::with(['form.manpower'])
  ->whereNotIn('status', [PurchaseOrder::INACTIVE])
  ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
  ->get();
```

Comment: read https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#chunking-results

Comment: read more https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#chunking-results

Answer (score 0):

A bit too late, but anyway…

You can try to load your relations lazily (dynamically) in this way:

```php
PurchaseOrder::whereNotIn('status', [PurchaseOrder::INACTIVE])
  ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
  ->get()
  ->load(['form.manpower']);
```

So your relations will be fetched only if you ask for properties of these relations.